# How to add Firebase Analytics data to a Flutter admin dashboard

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I am trying to develop a mobile application using flutter and I want to make a simple admin dashboard for this application. I want to add some tables from the Firebase Analytics Dashboard to this admin dashboard, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking if firebase has an API to read from your console and reflect data. then you have to configure your backend to pull data continually or whenever you open admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Firebase has no API that would fetch analytics data. However, you can download Analytics report as a CSV file or export it to Google Sheets that you could use to supply your data for your admin page.

To export your Analytics report, just go on the Report page you want to export (e.g. Analytics Dashboard), select the *share* button and click on *download file* and select your export format.

[image]